# Exibir PDF em WebView

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para um Laboratório de Análises Clínicas. O mesmo possui um sistema online onde pode visualizar os resultados.

No site, possui uma lista com todos os exames do cliente e quando clico no link para abrir o exame, ele carrega um PDF em uma nova guia, isso pelo Desktop. Pelo Mobile, quando clico no mesmo, ele parece abrir uma guia em branco no WebView, mas não carrega nenhum PDF, sem fazer o Download do PDF.

Meu Codigo:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewResultados);

    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setSupportZoom(false);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    wv.loadUrl("http://187.17.196.42:8181/ConcentWeb/servlet/hlab8000");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: Eu utilizo essa biblioteca [Android PdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) para visualizar os arquivos pdf. Veja se para você ela é útil.

Answer (score 3):

#### Opção 1

Usar o *viewer* do Google Drive. Veja como deve ficar:

```
WebView ws = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
ws.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
ws.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

<sup>**obs.:** É importante observar o limite de uso em relação ao Google Drive.</sup>

#### Opção 2

Usar o [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), projeto open-source [do Mozila](https://github.com/mozilla), que talvez seja a opção mais viável pois não possui limite de uso. Basta baixar e copiar o projeto para seu `assets`. Dê um uma lida em [Viewer options](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Viewer-options) para ver mais opções além do básico. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" + pdf  + "#zoom=page-width");
```

Comment: O problema como você disse é o limite de uso, porque a pagina mostra todos os exames do cliente, então se ele quiser consultar vários fica dificil

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar abrir o PDF com auxilio do Google Drive,
https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://educere.org.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/exemplo.pdf

PS: Dentro da web view, utilizando ionic + inappBrowser funcionou para algo que precisei

Comment: Diego, testei essa opção, mas no meu caso não serviu