# Como usar uma Intent para abrir um arquivo PDF pelo aplicativo padrão do android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um aplicativo android, e queria saber como faço para abrir um arquivo PDF que estará no Firebase em meu aplicativo. Não preciso que ele baixe o arquivo, simplesmente uma intent onde eu passe o caminho do arquivo (no caso o link) e ao clicar no botão o aplicativo padrão do android abra e renderize o arquivo.
O que eu tenho feito atualmente é um webview que abre o link do pdf pelo google docs, porém **não está funcionando mais** e por isso queria que o pdf fosse aberto através do leitor padrão do celular.
Abaixo o código Java do botão que chama o webview:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(PdfList.this, WebViewPDF.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            String pdf = "AQUI ENTRA O LINK DO PDF NO FIREBASE";
            WebViewPDF.OpenPDF.setPdf(pdf);
            Intent intent = new Intent(PdfList.this, WebViewPDF.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

E abaixo o código do webview que abre o PDF na tela dentro do aplicativo

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String pdf = OpenPDF.getPdf();

    WebView mWebView = new WebView(WebViewPDF.this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
    setContentView(mWebView);
}
public abstract static class OpenPDF extends WebViewPDF{
    private static String pdf;

    public static void setPdf(String pdfLink){
        pdf = pdfLink;
    }
    public static String getPdf(){
        return pdf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas isso ai depende se o dispositivo tem instalado algum leitor de PDF; Se por um acaso não tiver, isso ai não vai funcionar. Mas você pode fazer uma chamada de WebView para visualizar. O que você já fez?! Tem como inserir na pergunta?!

Comment: @acklay atualizei a pergunta com o código atual do webview que to utilizando.

Comment: Acredito eu que não existe leitor padrão no Android. Geralmente se não tiver algum app que leia pdf, o arquivo não será reconhecido. Olha essa essa resposta, na segunda opção. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218776/35406 Provavelmente irá te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de tentar criar um `intent` é que pode ser que não tenha nenhum leitor de PDF instalado no dispositivo. Algumas empresas colocam leitores como aplicativos padrões, porém isso não acontece sempre.

Já a questão de abrir o leitor do Google Drive pelo WebView, você provavelmente tem enfrentado problemas pois existe tem limite de visualização. Então uma segunda opção que seria o [**pdf.js**](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), projeto open-source [do Mozila](https://github.com/mozilla), que talvez seja a opção mais viável pois não possui limite de uso. Basta baixar e copiar o projeto para seu `assets`. Dê um uma lida em [Viewer options](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Viewer-options) para ver mais opções além do básico. Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=" 
    + pdf  + "#zoom=page-width");
```

Eu mostrei essa essa mesma opção [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218776/35406).

Eu testei e acabou dando um erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para corrigir, basta entrar no arquivo `viewer.js` e comentar o seguinte código:

```
if (fileOrigin !== viewerOrigin) {
    throw new Error('file origin does not match viewer\'s');
}
```

**OBS.:** A versão mínima para funcionamento é [API Level: 16 Android 4.1 (JELLY_BEAN)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html), pois é necessário atribuir `true` para os métodos [`setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)) e [`setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(boolean)), para permitir que acesse ao conteúdo de um arquivo a partir da URL e de qualquer origem. Arquivos internos não fiz nenhum teste ainda. Assim que puder fazer, crio uma complementação aqui.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Comment: Tentei utilizar seu código, porém ele não conseguiu abrir o PDF, apareceu apenas a seguinte mensagem de erro: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_1un0ahgDUTTdwekZnX1BuX1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TúlioMarcos Editei. Encontrei o erro e a solução. Boa sorte!

Comment: Funcionou agora, obrigado!

Comment: Qual a API mínima que pode ser utilizada o pdf.js considerando que pelo código de exemplo postado acima se está utilizando WebChromeClient?

Comment: @Henqsan editei a pergunta. Eu não fiz teste com arquivos pdf internos, mas externos só funciona com JellyBean.

Comment: @acklay obrigado!

Comment: @acklay para abrir o arquivo pdf local basta informar o caminho `String pdf = "file:///android_asset/arquivo.pdf";`. Uma dúvida, existe a possibilidade de haver uma interação entre o javascript e o webview de forma que seja possível por exemplo capturar o número da página do arquivo pdf?